# opencart 3.0 probmem, the site don't send email in contac-us section

Tags: php, email, model-view-controller, opencart

Hi Currently I manage a site in OPENCART, I have the problem that: in the section about us: when I click send, the email is not sent. Below I show you the "view" part since my intention is to go from the front to the back, someone tell me where to continue?

```
           <form action="{{ action }} " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><h2>{{ text_contact }} </h2></legend>
                 <p>{{ comment }}</p>
              
              <div class="form-group required">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ name }}" id="input-name" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ entry_name }} *"/>
                  {% if error_name %} 
                  <div class="text-danger">{{ error_name }} </div>
                  {% endif %} 
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group required">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ email }}" id="input-email" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ entry_email }} *" />
                  {% if error_email %} 
                  <div class="text-danger">{{ error_email }} </div>
                  {% endif %} 
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group required">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <textarea name="enquiry" value="{{ entry_enquiry }}" rows="10" id="input-enquiry" placeholder="{{ entry_enquiry }} *" class="form-control">{{ enquiry }}</textarea>
                  {% if error_enquiry %} 
                  <div class="text-danger">{{ error_enquiry }} </div>
                  {% endif %} 
                </div>
              </div>
              {{ captcha }} 
            </fieldset>
            <div class="buttons">
              <div class="pull-left">
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('https://supertortillamachines.com/index.php?route=information/contact/success')"><span>{{ button_submit }} </span></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming mail is working otherwise from your website, you need to start debugging the code. find out what controller function is being called by form action="{{ action }} " (it will be visible in the rendered page)  and relate to a directory/file/function name.

From there at the start of the function put in a `echo "hello";` just to see if it is even getting that far. and then just start looking at the data passed to the function and the flow of the code to see where it bombs out.